# Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 13.0.2

Tags: java, android, apache-cordova, mac

Me ajudem por favor!
Não sei mais o que fazer... já li todos as ajudas que falam sobre isso e até agora não consegui resolver!

> Tiagos-iMac:app tiago$ cordova run android Checking Java JDK and
>   Android SDK versions ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/tiago/Library/Android/
>   (recommended setting) ANDROID_HOME=/Users/tiago/Library/Android/
>   (DEPRECATED) Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected
>   version: 13.0.2 Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH
>   environment variables. Tiagos-iMac:app tiago$

Como posso resolver isso?

### .bash_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/Sdk/emulator
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/Sdk/tools
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/Sdk/tools/bin
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/


PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/Sdk/emulator
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/Sdk/tools
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/Sdk/tools/bin
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/

export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=~/.android/avd
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-6.1/bin
```

### Java

```
Tiagos-iMac:~ tiago$ java -version
java version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
Tiagos-iMac:~ tiago$
```

Answer (score -2):

Quem tiver o mesmo problema, remova todos os java instalados.

e quando for instalar, deve usar o java de desenvolvimento.